Assign file ownership in Linux
I want to assign file ownership in Linux.
sudo chown (new owner) (file name?)

What should I use for file name?

It's unusual to want to change ownership of something without knowing what you want to change ownership of. You might want to explain further what issue you are trying to solve. Do this by editing your question.

Ypu change file ownership per file with chown. If you want to setup automatically group ownership on new file on a specific directory, you can ask such question (if you do not find already the answer, which I think it is already answered in this site).

Kali is not intended for less-experienced users. If you have questions at this level, it is suggested that you use a more user-friendly distribution.

In the sudo chown command, you replace (file name) with the actual name or path of the file (or directory) that you want to change ownership of. Here's the syntax you have to use:
sudo chown new_owner file_name

An example of that:
sudo chown alice example.txt


The chown command takes as argument the filename, the new owner you want to assign file ownership to, and optionally the new group you want to assign file ownership to.
So, to assign the file myfile to owner kevin:
chown kevin myfile

To assign the file myfile to owner kevin and group hackers:
chown kevin:hackers myfile

You can always rename the file later via mv or rename.
The chown manpage is here.
